# $timeout - Number is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having a terrible time getting $timeout to work in an Angular directive.  Essentially even the most simplistic implementation continues to throw a TypeError: number is not a function error.

I've done a bit of research and for the life of me can't figure out what is going wrong.

```
$timeout(function(){
   console.log('$timeout called');
}, 500);
```

I'm only left to assume $timeout expects a function for the delay which makes no sense unless I am reading the documentation incorrectly.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Thanks in advance.

Stripped out everything but the $timeout implementation from the directive.

```
    (function (window, angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('bento.numberinput', ['bento.services'])
    .factory('$helper',[
      function(){

       // code here

      }
    ])
    .directive('bentoNumberInput', [
      '$helper',

      function ($helper) {
      return {
        restrict  : 'A',
        require   : '?ngModel',
        replace   : false,
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller, $timeout){

          $timeout(function(){
             console.log('$timeout called');
          }, 500);

        }
      };
    }]);

})(window, window.angular);
```

Comment: Looks clean to me. You sure `$timeout` isn't being overridden somehow from the injection? Maybe you want to put all of the code up here?

Comment: To be more specific, can you show how `$timeout` dependency is defined in your directive?

Comment: Well, it works for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efutf7f2/)

Comment: Thanks for the responses folks, I've updated the original post to show how timeout is being defined.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention how I was injecting timeout, currently it's being done through link.  While an Angular beginner I didn't think it would hold much weight, but now I am thinking it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$timeout needs to be injected at the top, much like your $helper, by the directive name and into the function as well since you're using the array form

```
.directive('bentoNumberInput', [ 
  '$helper', '$timeout',

  function ($helper, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict  : 'A',
    require   : '?ngModel',
    replace   : false,
    transclude: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller){

      $timeout(function(){
         console.log('$timeout called');
      }, 500);

    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed the solution to my problem.  Cheers.